# execution of external program fails in matlab

Tags: matlab, system

I call ghostscript with

```
cmd = [gs ' -sOutputFile="' outputFile '" -f "' inputFile '"'];
status = system(cmd); % Run Ghostscript.
```

which results in commands like this one:

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -dUseFlateCompression=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dHaveTrueTypes -r600 -dGraphicsAlphaBits#4 -dTextAlphaBits#4 -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile="C:\SVN\google code\latexfigure\trunk\example\TEMP9058.png" -f "C:\SVN\google code\latexfigure\trunk\example\TEMP9058.pdf"
```

This is valid code and works in the command windows of windows. 
But matlab complains:

> Der Befehl "gswin32c.exe" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder 
>   konnte nicht gefunden werden.

The 'gswin32c' is in the path of windows and I restarted matlab already. 
What could go wrong?

Comment: Try and use the absolute path to your executable, if that fixes the solution then it would seem Matlab is doing something unexpected with  the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path Matlab sees for terminal commands is not equal to the Windows path. Thus, if you know where `gswin32c.exe` lives, you should specify the full path to the program when calling the system command.

Comment: After a restart of windows it worked and the path is equal to that from windows with the only difference that the matlab path is added. Where is documented that it should be different?

Comment: Ok, then everything is fine. The path is actually an issue on Mac, so I assumed that this could be a problem with Windows as well.